# How to control the other object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using c# for Unity, I have two objects (the current one which is the one that has the script file, and the other one that I want to change its material), this is my code :

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public Material[] material;
Renderer rend;

public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.enabled = true;
    rend.sharedMaterial = material [0];

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
    {   // Here is the problem, it will change the color of the current object not the other one
        rend.sharedMaterial = material [1];
    }
}
}
```

Please help!
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rend object is set in the start method. I think you need to get the other gameObject like:

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
{
  var changeColorObject = other.GetComponent<Renderer>();
  changeColorObject.sharedMaterial = material [1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) on the other variable to access the [`Renderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html) then you can access its [`sharedMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html).

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
    {
        //Get Renderer or Mesh Renderer
        Renderer otherRenderer = other.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        otherRenderer.sharedMaterial = material[1];
    }
}
```